# Symfony 2, default for whole resource

Tags: symfony, routes, yaml

I need to pass default for whole resource, just I can't find instruction how.

This works, but I don't want to set it for every routing

```
#routing.yml

AdmWatraBundle_admin:
    resource: "@AdmWatraBundle/Resources/config/routing_admin.yml"
    prefix:   /adm

#routing_admin.yml

AdmWatraBundle_admin_index:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AdmWatraBundle:Admin:index, _i18n_disabled: true }
```

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work

```
#routing.yml

AdmWatraBundle_admin:
    resource: "@AdmWatraBundle/Resources/config/routing_admin.yml"
    prefix:   /adm
    defaults: { _i18n_disabled: true }

#routing_admin.yml

AdmWatraBundle_admin_index:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AdmWatraBundle:Admin:index }
```

How can I manage to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be implemeneted in Symfony 2.1

( https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/2e1344eb7 )